# How to get file names from Web directory - Python code

Tags: python, web, filenames

I would like to know how to get a list of filenames (.jpg image files) that are stored on a server.

I am looking for code which stores all the filenames (with their extension) in an Excel table or in the CSV format.

Any tips will be very helpful.

Answer (score -2):

It's pretty easy to get the filenames of all files stored in a certain folder, and you can easily write it in a file (in whatever format you want) :

```
import os
filenames = os.listdir('path to directory')
logFile = open('filenames.txt')
for name in filenames:
    logFile.write(filename)
logFile.close()
```

You must execute this code on your server, so make sure you can execute Python code on it.

Once that's done, you can retrieve it from your server using the `urllib2` module : [How do I download a file over HTTP using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python)

Comment: This not working. The question is about files that are on a web directory, not a local folder.